# numpy polynomial interpretation

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Polynomial.fit and get the following polynomial:

polynomial.**str**()
'0.8447708645677164 - 0.09751307764485126 x**1 - 0.039531273903863295 x**2'

but when I perform

polynomial(0),
it shows 0.9027526683087044.

But I thought if we input 0 into x, shouldn't it be 0.8447708645677164 instead?

Comment: Maybe provide your code that we can test. I tested on my side and get the right value.  from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

polynomial = Polynomial([0.8447708645677164 ,  - 0.09751307764485126, - 0.039531273903863295])

print(polynomial)

print(polynomial(0)) It prints 0.8447708645677164 - 0.09751307764485126 x^1 - 0.039531273903863295 x^2 then 0.8447708645677164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the corrrect way

```py
import numpy as np

p = [-0.039531273903863295, -0.09751307764485126, 0.8447708645677164 ]
val = np.polyval(p, 0)
print(val)
```

**output**
0.8447708645677164